# How to multiply 2 floats in F#?

Tags: f#

```
type Vector = {
        x: float
        y: float
}

let mult (v: Vector) = 
   v.x * v.x
```

now vscode underlines v.x and sais: "This value is not a function and cannot be applied." So whats going on here?

**UPDATE**

code above was placed after next code:

```
let (/) (v1: Vector, a: float) = 
    {x = v1.x / a
     y = v1.y / a}
```

If I place mult function above this operator overload, than this works..

Comment: I don't get the error. Try restarting VSC?

Comment: That works fine for me. Do you have Ionide installed? Does VSCode recognize that your file is F# (as far as I know it is inferred from the file extension)? You can see the Language Mode on the bottom right corner in VSCode window.

Comment: tried restarting, same thing. Using Ionide, f# is recognized. so embarresing not being amble to multiply or eaven add two floats lol

Comment: Make sure all your whitespace is the same as in your question. Try copying from your question back into your code.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out the `*` operator? Then you'd get `v.x v.x`, which F# would read as "call the function `v.x`, and pass it `v.x` as its one parameter". That would cause the "this is not a function" error you're seeing.